# keycloak saml identity broker

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak SAML Identity Broker and need access to SAML assertion from IDP after user authentication.
Is it possible and if yes then how? Will appreciate if I could get guidance regarding the same.

I have created Keycloak SAML Identity Provider